# click function not firing on image jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT** 
So everyone is perfectly clear, this table is being created after I query my db and then take the query, run a while loop and inflate my table. AKA create it on the fly, dynamically, programatically, however you'd like to label it. This table does not exist in html, and does not exist anywhere before the query. So I was at fault for not explaining this to begin with. I did mention it in the comments but I should have been more clear.

---

I have an image with a class, when I click it I want it to alert me the value under Job# but nothing is happening. I created a fiddle to demonstrate and the fiddle works perfectly. I don't understand what's going on.

Heres the fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHAtG/4/).

and here is the actual code

**php generating table**

```
echo "<table class='projects_contentTable'>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "" . "</th>";
echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/edit.png' class='edit_project_record'/>" . "</td>";
echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<img src='images/view.png' class='view_project_record'/>" . "</td>";    
echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . "16" . "</a>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";               
echo "</table>";
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.view_project_record').click(function() {
    var project_id = $('.projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').text();
    alert(project_id);
});
```

now I realize that in the fiddle I'm using paragraph tags to simulate the image. So I thought maybe, that was the reason, silly as it may be. So I tried changing my code to this, just to be sure.

```
echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<p class='edit_project_record'>" . "<img src='images/edit.png'/>" . "</p>" . "</td>";
echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<p class='view_project_record'>" . "<img src='images/view.png'/>" . "</p>" . "</td>";
```

It still doesn't fire when I click on the image. I know click functions work on pictures as I have another one that fires events when clicked from a `jQuery` function. Why is this one not working? Is there a rule about images in tables I don't know about?

Comment: Why are you "echoing" PHP code and not just outputting it normally?

Comment: @Neal this table is being inflated from a query. I was just simplifying to make the question easy to understand without fluff.

Comment: @Neal the only difference between the code you see and mine is instead of echoing "16" its "row['id']". I just didn't want to confuse peopel

Comment: You're attaching event handlers before the elements exist. Use event delegation via `$(someContainer).on('click', '.view_project_record', ... );`

Comment: @jbabey bleh, I hadn't even thought about that, you're right! Thanks. You can post that as an answer if you like. I'll accept it. Nevermind looks like two people beat you to it, lol

Comment: Just set the handler after images are added in the DOM like any other handlers for any other elements

Comment: Event delegation is only the correct solution if OP is dynamically creating elements, which I don't think he is. As far as I can see he's only outputting them from the PHP, so the document.ready wrapper is the correct solution.

Comment: @MrCode or set the handler just before closing body tag :)

Comment: man there is a lot of down voting going on in this question. Answers, my question. People are down vote happy. I thought I asked a well formulated question and I had done the research, my mind just wasn't thinking the way it should of been. Oh well

Comment: @i_me_mine There is nothing wrong with your question my friend. +1
Some people are getting this as a joke.

Comment: @DKM well I put an edit just for the heck of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your event handler in the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view_project_record').click(function() {
        var project_id = $('.projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').text();
        alert(project_id);
    });
});
```

It works in the fiddle because you have set the fiddle to run your code `onload`, but your actual code appears to be missing the document ready wrapper, and so most likely the element doesn't exist when it tried to attach the click event.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the contents to in `$(window).load` or `$(document).ready`

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.view_project_record').click(function () {
        var project_id = $('.projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').text();
        alert(project_id);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view_project_record').click(function() {
        var project_id = $('.projects_contentTable td:nth-child(3) a').text();
        alert(project_id);
    });
});
```